# Printing in ICEfaces using ace:printer

Tags: icefaces-3

I am quiet new in ICEfaces. Version I am using is 3.0.0.

I am trying to print a webpage using ace:printer.

My page contains a data table with vertical scroll bar.

My problem is it only prints the part of page that is visible on browser.

It is not printing the whole data table.

I do agree that as per the specifications of ace:printer it is mentioned that "In the case of tables, only visible columns / rows / panels will be printed."

How should I print the whole page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sort of workaround I did :

1. Have an Ajax Listener

> ```
> <h:commandLink id="printImgLnk1">
> <h:graphicImage id="printerImg1"
> value="/images/printIcon.png"
> alt="Print"
> style="border: 0 none;" />
> <h:outputText id="printAll" value="Print ALL" style="text-decoration:none" />
> <ace:ajax event="click" execute="@this" listener="#{backingBean.printListener}"/>
> </h:commandLink>
> ```

So, have a boolean print in your backend bean : lets say boolean print=false;

Now the listener :

```
 public void printListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent e){
setPrint(true);
}
```

now in your .xhtml where data table is present, do this for the scrollable attribute :

```
scrollable='#{!backingBean.print}'
```

Thanks!